# Copy values from one field to the same field of a different record based on names

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-update, mysql-5.7

I have a table with the following example data:

| ID | Name | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XX100 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | YY101 |  |  |
| 3 | XX100-TS | 123 | -123 |
| 4 | XX100-RS | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | XX100-LS |  |  |
| 6 | YY101-TS | 234 | -234 |
| 7 | YY101-RS |  |  |
| 8 | YY101-LS | NULL | NULL |

What I need to do is update the lat and long fields for IDs 4-7 to match the lat/long of the ones without the L/R at the end. So basically XX100-L will have the same lat/long as XX100, YY101-L will have the same as YY100 and so on.

Unfortunately as you can see some of the fields are NULL and some are blank, the desired output of this would be:

| ID | Name | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XX100 | 123 | -123 |
| 2 | YY101 | 234 | -234 |
| 3 | XX100-TS | 123 | -123 |
| 4 | XX100-RS | 123 | -123 |
| 5 | XX100-LS | 123 | -123 |
| 6 | YY101-TS | 234 | -234 |
| 7 | YY101-RS | 234 | -234 |
| 8 | YY101-LS | 234 | -234 |

Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have managed to answer the second portion of my question with the following SQL:

```
UPDATE tab AS t1
JOIN tab AS t2 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Name, '-', 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.Name, '-', 1)
SET t1.lat = t2.lat,
    t1.`long` = t2.`long`
WHERE t1.Name NOT LIKE '%-TS' AND t2.Name LIKE '%-TS';
```

Comment: I see no update on lat long values, into the expected output, apart from updated names. Is the expected output missing some infos?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Src data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (#5). Desired final data state as a table (#3).

Comment: @lemon I'm not sure what happened, it was fine when I was writing the question, I have edited it now back to what it should be so you can see the desired output!

Comment: An observation: If your numbers are in degrees, they're bogus. Latitude runs from -90 at the south pole to 90 at the north pole. And longitude usually runs from -180 to 180.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `UPDATE` statement, you can apply a self join, that matches on the partial common part of the "*Name*" value, obtainable with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.

```
UPDATE     tab t1
INNER JOIN tab t2
        ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Name, '-', 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.Name, '-', 1)
SET t1.lat = t2.lat,
    t1.long = t2.long
WHERE t1.lat IS NULL AND t2.lat IS NOT NULL;
```

**Output**:

| ID | Name | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XX100 | 123 | -123 |
| 2 | YY101 | 234 | -234 |
| 3 | XX100-TS | 123 | -123 |
| 4 | XX100-RS | 123 | -123 |
| 5 | XX100-LS | 123 | -123 |
| 6 | YY101-TS | 234 | -234 |
| 7 | YY101-RS | 234 | -234 |
| 8 | YY101-LS | 234 | -234 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8YBcgm47tqHASjW4pFff9b/3).

Comment: I have just checked and of course this DB and it is running MySQL 5.7.38, is there a way to do your above answer in this version @lemon?

Comment: Just updated to a streamlined one that works in both legacy and current MySQL environments.

Comment: much appreciated, I have another table that is near identical but ID's 1 and 2 would have -TS at the end with ID's 4-7 having -LS and -RS at the end, how easily could this query be adapted to change this table too using the -TS as the source for lat/long?

Comment: Update your post with it, and the expected output accordingly. Should be an easy fix, although seeing actual values would clear out doubts directly.

Comment: Updated as requested @lemon

Comment: Shouldn't the id be unique? If the id is not unique, the query gets quite slower, as you need extra aggregation.

Comment: @Ikthezeus Just required a minor tweak, check the updated answer. As a side note, when you update something about your post, you shall notify people: I realized you updated it only because I got notified of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by left joining with a list of names that have lat or long not null :

```
select t.ID, t.Name, s.lat, s.`long`
from mytable t
left join (
  select Name, lat, `long`
  from mytable
  where lat is not null or `long` is not null
) as s on t.Name like concat(s.Name, '%');
```

The update statement can be :

```
update mytable t
left join (
  select Name, lat, `long`
  from mytable
  where lat is not null or `long` is not null
) as s on t.Name like concat(s.Name, '%')
set t.lat = s.lat,
    t.`long` = s.`long`
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lcK7xbUp)